# Pig variable storage

Tags: variables, hdfs, apache-pig, hadoop2

Pig uses variables to store the data.

When I load the data from HDFS into the variable in pig. Where is the data temporarily stored?

What exactly happens in the background when we load the data into the variable ?

Kindy help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pig lazily evaluates most expressions. In most cases, it checks for syntax errors etc. Like,

```
a = load 'hdfs://I/Dont/Exist'
```

won't throw an error unless you use `STORE` or `DUMP` or something along those lines which result in the evaluation of `a`

Similarly, if a file exists and you load it to a relation and perform transformations on it, the file is spooled to `/tmp` folder usually and then the transformations are performed. If you look at the messages that appear when you run commands on `grunt`, you'll notice file paths starting with `file:///tmp/xxxxxx_201706171047235`. These are the files that store intermediate data.

Comment: U mean to say that when i execute a = load '/home/hadoop/pigdata/test' data is not stored into a variable. It is only stored when I execute dump a